# Libgdx Entity Gravity

Tags: java, libgdx

I really don't like using box2d with Libgdx, so I set up a map from Tiled to have a rectangle for every cell in the layer. I have a player set up that should fall if it is not touching one of the rectangle, but it slowly falls through the map.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < g.getBounds().size; i++) {
        Intersector.intersectRectangles(bounds, g.getBounds().get(i), intersection);
        if((bounds.overlaps(g.getBounds().get(i))) && intersection.y > g.getBounds().get(i).y) {
            vel.y = 0;
            if (MyInput.isPressed(MyInput.SPACE)) {
                vel.y = 5;
            }
        } else {
            vel.y-=.0005f;
        }
    }
```

The for loop goes through all the rectangles to check if the player is touching the top.

Comment: so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    boolean collides=false;
    for(int i = 0; i < g.getBounds().size; i++) {
        Intersector.intersectRectangles(bounds, g.getBounds().get(i), intersection);
        if((bounds.overlaps(g.getBounds().get(i))) && intersection.y > g.getBounds().get(i).y) {
            collides=true;
        }
    }

    if(collides){
        vel.y = 0;
        if (MyInput.isPressed(MyInput.SPACE)) {
              vel.y = 5;
        }
    }else{
        vel.y-=.0005f;
    }
```

The explanation of whats wrong with your code is on user789805 awnser

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looping over all the rectangles(?) and the vel.y value is overwritten by the state of later rectangles.

You could for example also use a boolean to indicate you are on a surface and set the vel.y after the loop.